# Where $x \in [1,2]$, find an upper bound on $|1-fl(x*fl(1/x))|$

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error

Where $x \in [1,2]$, find an upper bound on $|1-fl(x*fl(1/x))|$

Where $fl(x)$ rounds a number to the nearest IEEE 64-bit approximate encoded value.

#### My Work

64-bit IEEE has a 52-bit fraction with an implied leading 1.

With a hypothetical zero-bit fraction, the maximum approximation error would be $2^{-1}$. With a hypothetical $n$ bit fraction, the maximum approximation error would be $2^{-n-1}$. With a 52-bit fraction, the maximum approximation error would be $2^{-53}$.

The maximum error of $|1 - fl(x \cdot fl(1/x))|$ will be when $x$ is at maximum value of $x=2$ and approximation error is maximized so that $fl(x) = x + 2^{-53}$. This gives us a maximum approximation error of:

\begin{align*}
&= 2 \cdot (1/2 + 2^{-53}) + 2^{-53} - 1 \\
&= 2 \cdot (1/2 + 2^{-53}) + 2^{-53} - 1 \\
&\approx 3.33 \cdot 10^{-16}
\end{align*}

Is this right? Is it close?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = s\times 2^k$, where $1\leq s<2$. If $s = 1$, then $fl(1/x) = 2^{-k}$ and $|1 - fl(x \times fl(1/x))| = 0$.

Suppose, that $1 < s < 2$. Then $fl(1/x) = 1/x + \frac{d}{2}\times ulp(1/x)$ for some $-1 \leq d \leq 1$. Further, $ulp(1/x) = ulp(2/s\times 2^{-k-1}) = 2^{-k-1-p}$, where $p = 52$ is the precision of IEEE-754 64-bit floating point number (since $1 < 2/s < 2$).

Therefore $\phi \equiv x \times fl(1/x) = 1 + x\times 2^{-k-1-p}\times\frac{d}{2} = 1 + 2^{-p-1}\times\frac{sd}{2}$. Let $\operatorname{next}(x)$, $\operatorname{prev}(x)$ denote respectively next and previous  to $x$ representable number. We have $\operatorname{next}(1) = 1+2^{-p}$ and $\operatorname{prev}(1) = 1-2^{-p-1}$.

Since $1-2^{-p-1} < \phi < 1 + 2^{-p-1}$, we have $\operatorname{prev}(1) \leq \phi < \frac{1}{2}(1 + \operatorname{next}(1))$ and $\operatorname{prev}(1) < fl(\phi) \leq 1$, from which we conclude $|1 - fl(\phi)| \leq 1-\operatorname{prev}(1) = 2^{-p-1} = 2^{-53}$.

Comment: Experimentally, with a random number like `1.814904755469005`, using Julia, Scala, Python 2, Python 3, they all produce error of `1.11e-16` which is definitely greater than zero. So, the answer simply can't be zero.

Comment: You are right. There was an error in last rounding.